# How to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\cos(bx^2)dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

How to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\cos(bx^2)dx$? I'm seeing gaussian integral here. I tried different methods, but nothing helped

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch this post is not a duplicate of that one.  The fact that we have an $x^2$ here makes it fundamentally different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your integral can be re-written as
$$\frac{1}{2}\text{Re} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(a-ib)x^2} \, dx.$$
But this is just a Gaussian integral, albeit with a complex exponential, whose result is famous, and in this case is given by
$$\frac{1}{2} \cos(\phi/2)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}}},$$
where $\phi = \text{arg}\,z$, for $z = a - ib$.

Comment: are you sure that the imaginary part cancels out?

Comment: I am explicitly taking the real part of the answer, but there is still an imaginary part to the overall integral.

Comment: Now looks better

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $a > 0$.

One approach is to use a contour integral.  First, by symmetry note that
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\cos(bx^2)dx =
\operatorname{Re}\left[ 
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(-a + bi)x^2}\,dx
\right].
$$
Let $\omega = a - bi$.  We have
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(-a + bi)x^2}\,dx = 
\int_{\Bbb R_+} e^{-\omega z^2}\,dz.
$$
With the substitution $u = \omega^{1/2} z$, we rewrite this as
$$
\omega^{-1/2}\int_{\omega \Bbb R_+} e^{-u^2}\,du.
$$
By considering a triangular contour, we find that $\int_{\omega \Bbb R} e^{-u^2}\,du = \int_{\Bbb R} e^{-u^2}\,du$.  With that, we find
$$
I = \operatorname{Re}\left[ 
\omega^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx
\right] = 
\operatorname{Re}(\omega^{-1/2})\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} 
=\frac{1}{2} \cos(\phi/2)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}}},
$$
where $\phi = \arg(\omega)$.
This confirms the other answer's result.

Comment: I'm sorry to question you, but I'm not entirely sure that this is correct. How are you using Cauchy's theorem here? Even if that part is correct, I am under the impression that your final integral should be $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}/2$.

Comment: @Zachary the total integral over the closed contour is zero by Cauchy's theorem.  The rectangular contour can be broken to four integrals along a line: the two horizontal ("Gaussian" integrals) and the integrals along the two vertical sides.  In the limit as the width of the rectangle approaches $\infty$, the integral along the vertical contours goes to zero (in particular, each integral is at most equal to $e^{-aR^2}$, where $2R$ is the width of the rectangle).

Comment: @Zachary Thank you for the correction regarding the substitution; that was a silly mistake

Comment: @Zachary given that your formula is apparently famous, I've almost certainly missed something

Comment: Your approach would work if the integrand looked something like $e^{-a(x-ib)^2}$ (and indeed, I am quite familiar with the technique). However, in this case, I unfortunately still do not see how you have simplified the integral to be independent of $b$.

Comment: @Zachary Well observed; I guess I'm a bit rusty with all this.  I'll try to fix my answer

Comment: Are you sure the integral does not depend on $b$?

Comment: @lcv I am not; my answer as it is definitely wrong.  Eyeballing the correction confirms Zachary's result. Fixing my post now

Comment: @lcv see my latest edit

Comment: Now looks good. Small typo in the last expression (it's still complex)